# R: filtering data and calculating correlation

Tags: r

So I'm learning R at the moment and am stuck on finding a 'where' function (like the one in SQL).

What I am trying to do below is calculate the correlation between the temperature and humidity for each month (represented in csv as 1, 2, 3 ...)

The code I've used below has to create a new dataset after filtering the redundant data out of the 'main' dataset, and then calculate the correlation for each dataset separately.

```
airquality <- read.csv("C:/Users/Spitz/Documents/airquality.csv")

january <- airquality [!airquality$Month %in% c(2,3,4,5),]
february <- airquality [!airquality$Month %in% c(1,3,4,5),]
march <- airquality [!airquality$Month %in% c(1,2,4,5),]
april <- airquality [!airquality$Month %in% c(1,2,3,5),]
may <- airquality [!airquality$Month %in% c(1,2,3,4),]

cor(january$Temp, january$Humidity, use="complete.obs")
cor(february$Temp, february$Humidity, use="complete.obs")
cor(march$Temp, march$Humidity, use="complete.obs")
cor(april$Temp, april$Humidity, use="complete.obs")
cor(may$Temp, may$Humidity, use="complete.obs")
```

I was just wondering if there is a function that would behave like this:

```
cor(airquality$Temp, airquality$Humidity, where airquality$Month = 1)
```

Comment: Are you looking for the `subset` function?

Comment: You need `==` instead of `=` to test for equality. `dplyr::filter` works a lot like a SQL `where`, but you should probably learn to subset first. There are lots of good resources on the [R tag info page](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info).

Comment: try `which`, you can open up a help page and learn

Answer (score 1):

Just subset using regular `[`.

```
cor(airquality[airquality$Month == 1, c("Temp", "Humidity")])
```